# Magento - Adobe Edge animation not working

Tags: javascript, magento, adobe-edge

I'm trying to include an Adobe Edge animation within a managed page but it's not working.
In firebug, I see the errors:

TypeError: A is not a function
[Stopper sur une erreur]

...ymbol.bindTriggerAction(compId,symbolName,"Default Timeline",0,function(sym,e){}...

cartonEdge_Actions.js (ligne 4)

In my theme's page.xml file, I have declared the Edge-generated javascripts as follows:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>devoption/carton_edgePreload.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>devoption/carton_edge.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>devoption/carton_edgeActions.js</script></action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem: The images refered to in my carton_edge.js file were not found.
That's because the image directory is calculated by the script using the site's base URL ending with index.php.

A solution is to override the image directory in the script with the full path to the images directory.

You'll find the image directory variable searching for "var im=" in the script